# Access checkbox thats in another file using javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have two files that  i am trying to work with they are both cshtml files with javascript. On of the files has a checkbox that I am trying to effect with javascript. Is it possible to set a checkbox to "checked" if you are using javascript in a separate file? or say check the results of an if statement from a different file so that I can set it to "checked"?

I have a script in File2 that is running to check if there is an ID to load a tab by default. When that runs, I would like to use it to set the checkbox in File1 to "checked". Is this at all possible?

File1:

```
<script>
    var defaultID = 0;
    if (window.defaultUserID != null)
        defaultID = window.defaultUserID;
</script>
<div> . . . 
<label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" id="showVoidedInfo" data-bind="checked: ShowVoids" /> Show Voids</label>
. . . </div>
```

File2:

```
@{
    bool loadUsersTabByDefault = false;

    if (ViewBag.LinkableId != null && ViewBag.LinkableId == 1)
    { 
        loadUsersTabByDefault = true;
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.loadUsers !=null && window.loadUsers == true){
        window.loadUsersTabByDefault = true;
        window.defaultUserID = window.defaultID;
        document.getElementById("showVoidedInfo").checked = true;
    }
    else
        window.loadUsersTabByDefault = false;

</script>
<div> . . . </div>
```

Comment: are both files loaded in the same page together?

Comment: File2 is loaded first and then the information in File1 is loaded to populate a particular section on the page that is created from File2. There is a tab section at the bottom of File2. when the user selects a particular tab, File1 is used to display that information.

Comment: when the tab is selected, is a new browser window or tab opened? Otherwise, you should be able to access the checkbox, after both files are loaded.

Comment: no new tabs or windows are opened. it just displays the information at the bottom of the page the user is already on

Comment: ok, so, is this your code that is posted and you need help with it, or do you need help with new code to do what you need.

Comment: that is code that I currently have. the "document.getElementByID" line in File2 is the one that I can't get to work. I was trying to use it to set the checkbox in File1 to "checked".

Answer (score 0):

this might help...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    if (window.loadUsers !=null && window.loadUsers == true){
        window.loadUsersTabByDefault = true;
        window.defaultUserID = window.UserID;
        document.getElementById("showVoidedInfo").checked = true;
    }
    else
        window.loadUsersTabByDefault = false;
  }
</script>
```

or...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showVoidedInfo" data-bind="checked: ShowVoids" checked />
```

Comment: that's what I have in File2.
`document.getElementById("showVoidedInfo").checked = true;`. Even if I put it in File1, it doesn't set the checkbox.

Comment: use the onload event to ensure everything on the page is loaded before trying to set the checked property

Comment: that broke another part. and still didnt work. thinking bout just closing or deleting this question and forgetting about it.

Comment: can't you just set the default value of the checkbox to checked? rather than use script?

Comment: no. the default value needs to be unchecked. I'm just trying to set it to checked for a specific scenario.